# multiple pipes and fork

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am not sure if this is how it is supposed to be but what I am trying to do is, I have five processes and 1 parent. I want to use pipes to communicate between parents to children and children to children. But I could not make it work. can I do something like that,please see below. or do I have to create a pipe separately for each child to child ,and child to parent? can i just declare a pipe such mypipe[2] and use it for all communications?parent to children , children to children? or do i have to create a pipe for each communication?

```
int pid[5];
mypipe[6][2];
pipe(mypipe);
```

Comment: You have to create multiple pipes because one pipe is responsible for dedicated communication between 2 processes only.

Comment: If you have multiple children read from the same read end of a pipe, it would screw things up. Once you read something, it's taken out of the stream and no other child would be able to read it. How would you know the thing you took out was even meant for the child that read it?

Comment: I would suggest looking into shared memory. It would also reduce communication through the kernel.

Comment: A while back, I needed to have two way communication between some 40 processes.  I tried using pipes as a first approach.  The number of pipes grew exponentially with each new process added.  That soon became a nightmare to understand, debug, maintain.   In the end I used the System V message interface.  (msgctl(), msgsnd() and msgrcv())  Where each process would start a single message queue via msgctl() and each process would send a message to the desired recipient by using 'msgid' corresponding to the process to receive the message.